# Installing composer with Xampp on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, composer-php, phar

I installed Xampp on ubuntu 20.04 and then tried to install composer globally with the follwing commands :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php-cli unzip
cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

I get this error returned :

```
The phar extension is missing.
Install it or recompile php without --disable-phar

The iconv OR mbstring extension is required and both are missing.
Install either of them or recompile php without --disable-iconv
```

So I tried to see if the `phar` extension is activated, and it seems to be :

**phar config:**
[image]

The only odd thing I found is the location of the php.ini, in `phpinfo()` it tells me the path is :

**php.ini path**
[image]

But I get this result with php --ini :

```
php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/8.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Edit: I also tried to uncomment extension=php_phar.dll and I added myself extension=phar.so

Comment: Looks like you are using completely different versions of PHP for the webserver and the shell access

Comment: what is the output of this command `php -m`? do you find the phar extension in this list?

Comment: ```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
date
filter
hash
json
libxml
openssl
pcntl
pcre
Reflection
session
sodium
SPL
standard
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```
It looks like i have 2 versions of php installed isn't it ?

Comment: May be I should remove xampp entirely and reinstall everything

Comment: `extension=php_phar.dll` won't have any effect on a Ubuntu system